# tickFormatter doesn't show negative values in recharts

Tags: reactjs, recharts

I have a parent component like this:

```
const SalesLineChart: React.VFC = () => {
  const GlobalReportState = useGlobalReportState();
  const { storeId } = useActiveStoreState();

  const { data: getSalesTrendResult } = useGetSalesTrendReportQuery(
    {
      ...GlobalReportState,
      storeId: storeId,
    },
    { skip: !durationIsValid }
  );

  const formattedDateSalesTrendData: SaleReport[] = React.useMemo(() => {
    if (getSalesTrendResult) {
      const { data } = getSalesTrendResult.data;
      return data.map((item) => ({
        ...item,
        createdAt: formatDate(item.createdAt, "DD MMM", false),
      }));
    }
    return [];
  }, [getSalesTrendResult]);

  const formatYAxisTicks = React.useMemo(() => {
    return (
      getSalesTrendResult?.data.yAxis.tickList.map((item) =>
        parseFloat(item)
      ) || []
    );
  }, [getSalesTrendResult?.data.yAxis.tickList]);

  return (
    <ReportLineChart
      data={formattedDateSalesTrendData}
      lineChartKey="netAmountAggregate"
      xAxisKey="createdAt"
      yAxisDomain={[
        Number(getSalesTrendResult?.data.yAxis.minValue),
        Number(getSalesTrendResult?.data.yAxis.maxValue),
      ]}
      yAxisKey="netAmountAggregate"
      yAxisTicks={formatYAxisTicks}
      title="Tren Penjualan Bersih"
    />
  );
};
```

I have a child component like this:

```
const ReportLineChart: React.VFC<ReportLineChartProps> = ({
  data,
  xAxisKey,
  yAxisDomain,
  yAxisTicks,
  yAxisKey,
  lineChartKey,
  title,
}) => {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const theme = useTheme<AppTheme>();

  return (
    <Box paddingY={6} flexGrow={1}>
      <Text variant="h3" className={classes.title}>
        {title}
      </Text>
      <ResponsiveContainer aspect={3}>
        <LineChart data={data}>
          <CartesianGrid stroke={theme.palette.interface.neutral.light} />
          <XAxis
            dataKey={xAxisKey}
            tickLine={false}
            axisLine={false}
            tickMargin={10}
          />
          <YAxis
            type="number"
            dataKey={yAxisKey}
            domain={yAxisDomain}
            tickLine={false}
            axisLine={false}
            ticks={yAxisTicks}
            width={100}
            tickMargin={10}
            tickFormatter={(item) => currencyFormatter(item)}
          />
          <Line
            dataKey={lineChartKey}
            type="monotone"
            stroke={theme.palette.interface.teal.primary}
            fill={theme.palette.interface.teal.primary}
            strokeWidth="3"
          />
        </LineChart>
      </ResponsiveContainer>
    </Box>
  );
};
```

If is remove the `tickFormatter`, it shows up like this:
[image: No tickFormatter]

As you can see, it shows the negative value of `-2200000`. But if I add the `tickFormatter`, it shows this:
[image: tickFormatter added]

As you can see, there is no negative sign. Here is the `currencyFormatter` function:

```
export const currencyFormatter = (
  unformattedString: string,
  separator = "."
): string => {
  const floatValues = parseFloat(unformattedString).toString();
  const split = floatValues.split(separator);
  const decimal = split[1];

  const formattedString = new Intl.NumberFormat("id-ID", {
    style: "currency",
    currency: "IDR",
    minimumFractionDigits: decimal ? decimal.length : 0,
  }).format(Number(unformattedString));

  return formattedString;
};
```